# Filter Pipes doesn't work in nested component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to use filter pipes in my codebase. I have a container where I see a list of the items but my problem is that the container is having the nested component which loads the items. Here is the HTML for the container:

baord-container.component.html

```
 <div class="myTeamsWrapper">
  <form id ="filter">
    <label>Filter seasons by name:</label>
           <input type="text" value = "yyy" [(ngModel)] = "term" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" placeholder="Search by Season name!"/>
  </form>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let season of myseasons | gdfFilter: term" >
    <gdf-board-nav-list-items [season]="season"></gdf-board-nav-list-items>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
```

Now you can see in the above code we have gdf-board-nav-list-items ..the HTML of this component looks like this:

gdf-board-nav-list-items.html

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="loggedIn" (click)="myTeam()">
    <div class="leftIcon">
   </div>
    <div class="textContent">
      <!--Katy Tigers<span class="year">2017-2018</span>-->
   {{boardName}}
    </div>
    <div class="rightIcon">
      <div class="uw-icon-arrow-right-small arrowIcon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The typeScript of the above file :

gdf-board-nav-list-items.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'gdf-board-nav-list-items',
  templateUrl: './gdf-board-nav-list-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gdf-board-nav-list-items.component.scss']
})
export class GdfBoardNavListItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  public loggedIn;

 // term: string = 't';

  @Input() season;
  boardName;


  constructor(public frLocalUserService: FrLocalUserService, private router: Router, private frApi: FRApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('gdfBoardNavList season =' + this.season);
    this.frApi.getBoard(this.season, 0).subscribe(b => {
      this.boardName = b.name;
    });
    this.frLocalUserService.loggedIn.subscribe((state) => {
      this.loggedIn = state;
    });
  }
```

That's how we get the board name which is displayed in the list on ngOnInit() , now my gdfFilter is currently searching the boardID which goes to gdf-board-nav-list-items.ts but it's not able to search with board name . How can i modify my code so that when i search using board name i get selected results only .

here is my gdffilter.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'gdfFilter'
})
export class GDFFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any, term?: any): any {
    // Check if the search term is undefined or fi nothing is entererd in the search box.
    if (!term ) {return values; }
     // return updated search array.
     return values.filter(function(x){
      // lowers the case of the search term and then return the matching vslues.
      //  alert(x);
       console.log(values);
      // return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
       return x.name;
    });
  }  
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may give [async pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-impure-asyncpipe) a look for your problem.

Comment: hi @Myonara I tried looking into async pipes. I am not quite sure how it can be used to solved my problem.